# How to run a function/process when waiting for reading a character from user?

Tags: assembly, x86, 32-bit, irvine32, pong

I am new to assembly and trying to build a kind of pong game where a ball hits the wall and we use a paddle to reflect the ball back towards the wall. I am using the Irvine32 library in this project and using the "ReadChar" to accept a input from the user and move the paddle accordingly. But during this procedure, I want the ball to keep moving. Is there any way to wait for the user Input for a specific amount of time then move on with the program so that I can move the ball? If not, is there any other way this behaviour can be achieved?

I will add a small snippet of the code below which should show enough about the working of the program.

```
.code
main PROC
    
    call DrawPlayGround
    call DrawPlayer
    call DrawBall

    gameLoop:
        call ReadChar
        mov inputChar, al

        ; exit Game if user types "x"
        cmp inputChar,"x"
        je exitGame

        cmp inputChar,"w"
        je moveUp

        cmp inputChar,"s"
        je moveDown

        moveUp:
            call UpdatePlayerUP
            dec yPosPlayer
            call DrawPlayer
            jmp gameLoop
        
        moveDown:
            call UpdatePlayerDOWN
            inc yPosPlayer
            call DrawPlayer
            jmp gameLoop
        

    jmp gameLoop


    exitGame:
    exit
main ENDP
```

Please excuse me if this is a silly question as I am a beginner and thank you for taking the time to answer the question.

Comment: Use `ReadKey` instead.

Comment: You're looking for what's called a non-blocking read -- returns data if available but doesn't wait otherwise; also tells if data was or wasn't there.